# Get different shades of a custom material UI theme primary color?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

In material UI we use a custom theme. Say we have somewhere:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#ED1C24'
        },
    },
});
```

Now to for a background I wish to have a "faint" version of this, like for the default colours.

In a default color one could do:

```
import * as React from "react"
import red from '@material-ui/core/colors/red';

function SomeComponent() {        
    const theme = useTheme();
    const shadedColor = red.A100;
    return <div style={{backgroundColor: shadedColor}}>hello world</div>
}
```

I could also use our primary color like:

```
import * as React from "react"
import red from '@material-ui/core/colors/red';

function SomeComponent() {        
    const theme = useTheme();
    const shadedColor = theme.palette.primary.main;
    return <div style={{backgroundColor: shadedColor}}>hello world</div>
}
```

But how do I get the different shades of this main color?

Answer (score 1):

You can add different version of your primary color like :

```
palette: {
    primary: {
        main: '#ED1C24'
        light: '#ED1C25',
        dark: '#ED1C26'
    },
},
```

Comment: yeah, and it does calculate those three, but is there no way to let material-UI calculate all shades? Instead of giving them manually?